# nodejs mocha async call fails to return. but works inside standard node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, amazon-web-services

can someone explain what is causing this failure please? I started out trying to plumb the amazon web services with a promise to tidy things up, but as I've stripped it back to get to the problem, I'm seeing a basic failure which is confusing me. In short, if I put the following AWS call in a file executed by Mocha, the function never returns, and neither path in the callback executes;

i.e, this fails, even outside of a describe block

```
new AWS.EC2(
    { 
        region: 'eu-west-1' , 
        secretAccessKey:"vcvcz", 
        accessKeyId:"ffczcvzxczxczxczx"
    }
).describeInstances(function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error); // an error occurred
    } else {
        console.log(data); // request succeeded
    }
});
```

but, if I take that code, stick in a standard node js file, it works. It appears Mocha is cancelling the request, or the callbacks are not bound, or being removed. Does anyone have any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, yes, the obvious answer was that I was using Mocha's default timeout. Setting 
    this.timeout =

and then calling done() on the return has solved this. Here is an async test function. Obviously, I will stub the actual call for testing purposes..

```
describe('addition', function () {
    it('should add 1+1 correctly', function (done) {

        this.timeout(10000);

        Loader.load(new AWS.EC2({ 
            region: 'eu-west-1' , 
            secretAccessKey:"xxxxx", 
            accessKeyId:"yyyyyyyyy"
        }))
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data)
            done();
        })
        .fail(function(error){
            console.log(error)
        })


    });
});
```